# How to detect a collision between one object and multiple objects in XNA 4.0 C#?

Tags: collision

I am new to XNA and CSharp programming so I want to learn to make a treasure hunting game as a beginning so I made a player(as a class) which can walk up, down, left and right. I made a Gem class also which the player can collide with and the gem disappears and a sound is played. But I want to make some walls that the player can collide with and stop so I made a class called Tile.cs (The wall class) and I made a void in it

```
public void CollideCheck(bool tWalk, bool bottomWalk, bool leftWalk, bool rightWalk,       Rectangle topRect, Rectangle bottomRect, Rectangle rightRect, Rectangle leftRect)
    {
        colRect = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height);

        if (this.colRect.Intersects(topRect))
        {
            tWalk = false;
        }

        else
            tWalk = true;

        if (this.colRect.Intersects(bottomRect))
        {
            bottomWalk = false;
        }

        else
            bottomWalk = true;

        if (this.colRect.Intersects(leftRect))
        {
            leftWalk = false;
        }

        else
            leftWalk = true;

        if (this.colRect.Intersects(rightRect))
        {
            rightWalk = false;
        }

        else
            rightWalk = true;
    }
```

Then, in the Game1.cs (The main Class) I made an array of "Tiles":

```
Tile[] tiles = new Tile[5];
```

And in the update void I made this:

```
foreach (Tile tile in tiles)
        {
            tile.CollideCheck(player.topWalk, player.bottomWalk, player.leftWalk, player.rightWalk,
                new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X, (int)player.Position.Y - (int)player.Speed.Y, player.currentAnim.FrameWidth, player.currentAnim.FrameHeight),
                new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X, (int)player.Position.Y + (int)player.Speed.Y, player.currentAnim.FrameWidth, player.currentAnim.FrameHeight),
                new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X + (int)player.Speed.X, (int)player.Position.Y, player.currentAnim.FrameWidth, player.currentAnim.FrameHeight),
                new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X - (int)player.Speed.X, (int)player.Position.Y, player.currentAnim.FrameWidth, player.currentAnim.FrameHeight));
        }
```

All those rectangles are the borders of the player but when I run the game the player doesn't collide with it so is there any way to fix this?

I can post the project if I am not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are in only, but you set their values inside the call. You have to declare them as `out` variables so that their value is sent back to the caller. Using `out` also makes sure you always set a value to them before exiting the function.

So change your function declaration to `public void CollideCheck(out bool tWalk, out bool bottomWalk, out bool leftWalk, out bool rightWalk, Rectangle topRect, Rectangle bottomRect, Rectangle rightRect, Rectangle leftRect)` and you get the values back.